# Flutter Web factoryFunction is PlatformViewFactory || factoryFunction is ParameterizedPlatformViewFactory is not true

Tags: flutter, webview, flutter-web

I got this error on Flutter Web WebView stuations

my code base look like this

```dart
ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
    'someKey',
    (int _) => getIframe()
      ..id = 'SomeIframeId'
      ..src = url ?? "data:text/html;base64,${Constant.contentBase64}"
      ..style.border = 'none' as html.IFrameElement,
  );
```

this code base was work before Flutter 3.3.0 update can anyone know solution

The complete error:
**Assertion failed: org-dartlang-sdk:///flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/platform_views/content_manager.dart:67:12
factoryFunction is PlatformViewFactory ||
factoryFunction is ParameterizedPlatformViewFactory
is not true**

Comment: I can't find any solution about this problem. Just downgrade flutter version to 3.0.5  for fix this problem

Comment: Hi, Were you able to go beyond 3.0.5? I need to be on 3.7.x and this issue is repeating...

Answer (score 1):

getIframe() method should return **IFrameElement**, not **dynamic**, or you should use braces:

```
ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
    'someKey',
    (int _) => (getIframe()
      ..id = 'SomeIframeId'
      ..src = url ?? "data:text/html;base64,${Constant.contentBase64}"
      ..style.border = 'none') as html.IFrameElement,
  );
```